# I can't get link_to for deleting to work in my app [RoR]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have tried to get this working with multiple different variations and it refuses to delete it. The box comes up asking me to confirm and when I do it takes me to the main show for that controller. I have tried link_to in multiple contexts for different controllers but none of them work. Oddly enough I had it working for a while and I'm not sure what I changed to cuase it to stop working again.

```
<%= link_to 'Delete Review', review, :method => "delete", :onclick => "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this review?')" %>

<%= link_to 'Delete Review',  review,  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

These are both of the ones I tried.

Comment: `code` def destroy
 @review = Review.find(params[:id])
 @host = Host.find(@review.host_id)
 @review.destroy
 redirect_to @host
  end  `code`

Answer (score 1):

What is the context of `review`?. You should pass a valid url as the second parameter.

E.g for your case you could do something like

```
<%= link_to "Delete Review", review_path(@review), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Nah even that doesn't work its confusing me. If I highlight over the link its just linking to show like /reviews/1 and then once I confirm it sends me there. Its like its ignoring delete? I'll post the entire view so you understand the context http://pastebin.com/r5STYqk1 Delete Host doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have included `jquery_ujs` in your application.js manifest - removing Rails' JS code will stop things like delete links (and also things like forms with `remote: true`) from working.

Alternatively, Javascript errors will interfere with the Rails' javascript handlers.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JcwKL7k6 Is this right or should I remove the // infront of them? I tried both and it didn't seem to effect anything.

Comment: no they should have the `//=` there. Do you have any Javascript errors in your console window?

Comment: ERm not that I can see.

Comment: Are you including `application.js` into your page?

Comment: Odd thing is even signing out of a session for example using a direct link localhost:3000/signout to sign out of a session gives a routes error. ITs like deleting doesn't work at all

Comment: That lends even more weight to you having a Javascript error that is preventing Rails' handlers from doing their jobs